# How to add Twitter oauth to iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to add this: https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone
The readme doesn't give a step by step so I just tried dragging the whole folder into my project and then when I try to compile I get a file not found error on #include

What do I do?

Comment: on #include libxml/xmlreader.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it's on the bottom of this page: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6136

In order to get your project to compile you’ll need to first include the libxml2 Framework (right click on your project and choose Add Exisiting Frameworks).

Now right click on your project and choose ‘Get Info’. In the build tab, scroll down till you see the ‘Search Paths’ section. In the ‘Header Search Paths’ field, add ‘$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2′

Finally, expand the Twitter+OAuth group in your project and then expand theMGTwitterEngine group. Open MGTwitterEngine.m and alter #define USE_LBXML 0 to #define USE_LIBXML 1.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add the following frameworks
libxml
And edit the header search path in the project settings to include

```
"$(SDK_DIR)"/usr/include/libxml2
```

For further info please read the following
[LibXML2.dylib and Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903939/libxml2-dylib-and-xcode4)

Comment: Ok it took me a long time but I figured out how to add that header search path. I still get the same error though.

Comment: $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

Comment: Ok that worked now I get the error "expected a type" on - (int)storeInKeychain:(SecKeychainRef)keychain appName:(NSString *)name serviceProviderName:(NSString *)provider;