# MGTwitterEngine on the iPhone Compiler Error:libxml2.dylib in Xcode4.3.2

Tags: iphone, ios4, libxml2, mgtwitterengine

I am using **Xcode4.3.2** and mac lionOs and unable to add **libxml2.dylib** because it's inbuilt file 
so am added that by Build settings
Build Settings:
Search Paths:

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
```

But i am getting 8 Errors of `MGTwitterEngine` on the iPhone Compiler `Error:libxml2.dylib`

Errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_xmlReaderForMemory", referenced from:


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser initWithXML:delegate:connectionIdentifier:requestType:responseType:URL:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o




 "_xmlTextReaderIsEmptyElement", referenced from:

  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValue] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _statusDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _userDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _hashDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser _directMessageDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.o




"_xmlTextReaderNodeType", referenced from:


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValue] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _statusDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _userDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _hashDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser _directMessageDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMiscLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterMiscLibXMLParser.o


  ...


  "_xmlTextReaderValue", referenced from:


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValue] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  "_xmlTextReaderRead", referenced from:


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValue] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _statusDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _userDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _hashDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser _directMessageDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMiscLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterMiscLibXMLParser.o


  ...


  "_xmlTextReaderConstName", referenced from:


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _statusDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _userDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _hashDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser _directMessageDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMiscLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterMiscLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterStatusesLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterStatusesLibXMLParser.o


  ...


  "_xmlStrEqual", referenced from:

  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _statusDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _userDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _hashDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser _directMessageDictionaryForNodeWithName:] in MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterMessagesLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterMiscLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterMiscLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterStatusesLibXMLParser parse] in MGTwitterStatusesLibXMLParser.o


  ...


  "_xmlFree", referenced from:


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser initWithXML:delegate:connectionIdentifier:requestType:responseType:URL:] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValueAsString] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValueAsDate] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValueAsInt] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o


  -[MGTwitterLibXMLParser _nodeValueAsBool] in MGTwitterLibXMLParser.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

how i resolve this..
share your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your target settings (select your project in file manager and then your target):

1. `Build Phases` => `Link Binary With Libraries`;
2. Press the small `+` button at the left-bottom
3. In appeared dialog type `libxml2.dylib` and select it (maybe you'll need to expand "iOS 5.1" or like that category pressing little black triangle to the right of folder icon)
4. Press Add button, and you're done.

**UPDATE:**
Check this ansver: [LibXML2.dylib and Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4903939/1032151)

Comment: I tried your idea also but in Link Binary with Libraries dont has such a file(libxml2.dylib). I am using Xcode4.3.2_lion and Mac lionOS

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. It went away when I linked the binary with the library.

```
Go to Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Library, click the plus sign and add "libxml2.dylib"
```