# #import <libxml/tree.h> file not found after xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, libxml2

Lastnight I updated my iPhone to iOS 6.1, my current version of xcode wouldn't build to the phone as I needed the newest version.

I went from xcode 4.5.2 to xcode 4.6, I made 0 changes in my project file.

What used to compile completely fine, now gives me a file not found error

```
#import <libxml/tree.h> 'libxml/tree.h' file not found
```

I have my search paths correctly linked up with

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
```

and libxml2 is linked and required in build phases.

Edit:

Peculiar I changed my search paths to the following and voila..

```
/usr/include/libxml2
```

Not sure why this has fixed this issue, could anyone enlighten me as to what's changed in xcode?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903939/libxml2-dylib-and-xcode4

Comment: Hmm I solved my issue by doing as above, I just don't understand what's changed between 4.5.2 and 4.6 to break my project

Comment: OMG, was that it? ty Bongeh that helped me 2 solve this issue in Xcode4.6.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Because we are now at 4.6.2. You could check out this directory: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/ that should be your SDKROOT. And check if /usr/include/libxml2 doesn't exist.

Comment: Does it matter what the Display name and setting name are?

Answer (score 66):

In your build settings, add the following to your Header Search Paths:

```
$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2
```

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood the question, the reason I had the problem was because I had done as you said above in the first place.

Comment: Just in case anyone is in the same situation I was: remember to add the search path also to the test target.

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

For me what worked was adding this to header search path:

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
```

Slightly difference from other answer, probably to do with newer version of Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

add:   $SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode6 and latest versions add this to your Header Search Paths:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
```

and remember to add the search path also to the test target.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded libxml2 on my mac and then:

```sh
If you need to have libxml2 first in your PATH run:                                                                                                                                                                                             
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find libxml2 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include"

For pkg-config to find libxml2 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig"
```