# import libxml/XMLReader.h not found xcode 5.1 and OS X Mavericks

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode

As in this link:

[LibXML2.dylib and Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903939/libxml2-dylib-and-xcode4/4904022)

and countless others I have still getting the (in)famous 'not found' error when

```
#import "libxml/XMLReader.h"
```

in my Xcode project. The difference being the other questions/answers are on xcode 4 and earlier Mac OS versions.

Has anyone resolved this on Mavericks? 10.9.x and Xcode 5.1? And if so, which solution (I haven't tried the drag/drop of the libxml file into the project - will Apple let that through?)

Comment: What is your *header search path* set to?

Comment: I've tried them all - see previously linked question. By your question are you implying you've rebuilt/run a project using that import statement on the OS and xcode levels?

Comment: No I've never even used libxml.

Comment: In order to resolve this: first find out what include paths are being used (look in the build log and open a single file's *compile line*). second go to the command line and find out where the header file you want is located.  Post the updated information into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Same my problem.

You should do these changes.

1-

[image]

2-

[image]